# How can I send file to phone with bluetooth using 32feet and OBEX?

Tags: c#, bluetooth, obex

I tried to send file to my mobile phone via bluetooth. I used dll form 32feet.com (that was InTheHand). I able to scan available bluetooth devices that can communicate but I can't send file to that device. I tried to connect with DeviceName but that occur following error "Bad request". And I also tried with device address but that also occur another error "InternalServerError". How can I fix it. I used ObexWebRequest and ObexWebResponse to request and get response. Thank.

Answer (score 0):

What version of 32feet.NET are you using? I'm the maintainer of the library and we stopped using `BadRequest` and `InternalServerError` a long time ago (2008).  If you use a newer version you'll get an exception which includes information about why the operation failed.

Also you need to use the DeviceAddress -- device name lookup isn't done. In the newer version you can use a ObexWebRequest constructor that takes a device address rather than a URL.

Answer (score 0):

This also seems to depend on the phone being used. I followed [this guy's example code](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2009/06/23/working-with-bluetooth-devices-using-c-part-2-obex.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage).

It worked perfectly with a Nokia 5230 but when I tried it with a Sony Xperia U, I got the "Bad Request" response code.